# SQL SUM of distinct rows.... I'm stuck!

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pivot

Been trying to put together an SQL query that sorts data into financial years (which I've sorted) and then SUMs it according to each distinct value in the claim_id column

table structure is: claim(id, claim_id, date, amount)

SQL so far is:

```
 SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN MONTH(date)>=4 THEN
            concat(YEAR(date), '-',YEAR(date)+1)
       ELSE 
            concat(YEAR(date)-1,'-', YEAR(date)) 
    END AS fyear,
    SUM(amount) AS total, claim_id
 FROM claim  
 GROUP BY fyear, claim_id 
 ORDER BY claim_id ASC, date ASC
```

At the moment I'm getting this

```
Array
(
    [fyear] => 2009-2010
    [total] => 567.89
    [claim_id] => 1
)
```

Which is really close, except of course because of the GROUP BY claim_id I'm getting another array for each distinct claim_id:

```
Array
(
    [fyear] => 2009-2010
    [total] => 106.76
    [claim_id] => 2
)
```

What I'd actually like is:

```
Array
(
    [fyear] => 2009-2010
    [total1] => 567.89
    [total2] => 106.76
)
```

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to clean up your SQL statement formatting. 4 spaces indents code.

Comment: Why do you really need it on columns? What's the problem of having the data in the rows!?

Comment: Because I'm trying to dynamically populate a table, each row in the table has the date, then a column for a total for each distinct claim_id. Just loads easier to build the table with php if the data comes out of the SQL in one row. Unless there's a better way to do it that i'm missing....

Comment: MySQL doesn't support dynamic columns for result sets like you want.  If you're really that desperate to have the data in a summary format, why not just loop through the result set in PHP and do the transformation yourself?  It's more work, but it will do what you want.

Comment: @W. Craig Trader: Use MySQL's Prepared Statements, which is MySQL's dynamic SQL syntax.

Comment: @OMGP, What I meant by 'dynamic columns' is a SQL query (called a Pivot) that returns a different number of **columns** depending upon the actual data being queried.  Standard SQL doesn't support queries like that, but some databases (noteably MS Access) do support queries like that.  In this case, MySQL does not.  In theory you could use a stored procedure to calculate the exact query, and then execute that query dynamically, but that's going to be very brittle code, and not to be trusted.

Comment: The other problem you'll have is you don't know how many claims you'll have, and no guarantee they will be sequential.. Additionally, what if in 2009, you have 20 claims, and in 2010, you have 50, and 2011 you have 8.  What would your table look like then...

Answer (score 0):

Would something like...

```
SELECT * FROM
    SELECT (CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(date)>=4 THEN
                     concat(YEAR(date), '-',YEAR(date)+1)
                ELSE 
                     concat(YEAR(date)-1,'-', YEAR(date)) 
                END AS fyear,
                SUM(amount) AS total, claim_id
        FROM claim
        WHERE claim_id = 1
        GROUP BY fyear
        ORDER BY date ASC),
    SELECT (CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(date)>=4 THEN
                     concat(YEAR(date), '-',YEAR(date)+1)
                ELSE 
                     concat(YEAR(date)-1,'-', YEAR(date)) 
                END AS fyear,
                SUM(amount) AS total, claim_id)
        FROM claim
        WHERE claim_id = 2
        GROUP BY fyear
        ORDER BY date ASC)
    FROM dual;
```

be of any use?

Comment: Hey, can't get your example working - parentheses mismatch somewhere? But in a similar vein I've considered grabbing the relevant claim_ids and then looping through selecting the data... but SQL in a loop ain't cool and I'm sure there's a tidy SQL query that will get what I want.

Comment: This will only work if there are only 2 claims per period (year).  As soon as there are 3 claims, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your existing query in another `SELECT` and using `GROUP_CONCAT` might do what you are after.  I've tested the SQL itself, but am not sure if the results are what you want - all your totals will appear in one column as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT fyear, GROUP_CONCAT(total) FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE 
           WHEN MONTH(date)>=4 THEN
                concat(YEAR(date), '-',YEAR(date)+1)
           ELSE 
                concat(YEAR(date)-1,'-', YEAR(date)) 
        END AS fyear,
        SUM(amount) AS total, claim_id
    FROM table1  
    GROUP BY fyear, claim_id 
    ORDER BY claim_id ASC, date ASC
) AS totals GROUP BY fyear;
```